# git fetch and pull

Tags: git, github

Here, we are migrating our source code to github, and this transaction is giving me headaches :)
what I did: I gone to our workspace (is an eclipse project), and did `git init` and `git add .` and then `git commit -am "first commit"`
everything worked fine, and then, i just pushed it to github. success too.
but there is a big problem: My friend just made a change on a file named `A.java` and I just changed `B.java`. ok, not a big deal. then, he pushed it to github. whei I try to push, my push is rejected. Ok, I did a `git pull github master` and then, push again, and now, my 'commit message' turns like `Merge branch 'master' of github.com:germantech/projectName`
Ok, what am I doing wrong?
ps: sorry about my english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong - when you do `git pull github master`, git goes to the repository indicated by the remote `github`, fetches everything needed for the `master` branch, and then merges it into your current branch.  Before the pull, you had the following history:

```
O --- A (master)
```

... where `O` is the commit with the message "firts commit" and `A` is the commit that introduced your changes to `A.java`.  Your friend, meanwhile, has the history:

```
O --- B (master)
```

... and that has been pushed to GitHub.  When your `git pull github master` merges that into your history, it creates a "merge commit" to represent the state of the tree with the changes from both `master` branches:

```
O --- B --- M (master)
 \         /
   ---A ---
```

If, instead, you wanted to keep the history linear, you could do `git pull --rebase github master`, which would instead would "replay" your commits that aren't in the remote version of the branch on top of that remove version of the branch:

```
o --- B --- A' (master)
```

Some people prefer that - I personally don't care.

Comment: will --rebase maintain my commit message? or will he change it?

Comment: --rebase doesn't changed my commit messages. what is preferable? pull or pull --rebase?

Comment: It will preserve the commit message (and the author information and the author date) - there's a separate commit date and committer information that will be updated.

Comment: @Luiz K.: it's entirely up to you - some people don't like seeing the splits and merges in their history for trivial changes that might as well be linear.  On the other hand, if you're incorporating work from a branch that was created for a particular topic, most people prefer to merge it to preserve that information in the commit graph.

Comment: nice. but I still doens't get why git is merging everything and changing our commit messages to that automatic 'merge branch master bla bla bla' thing if we changed different files. is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @Luiz K.: It's not changing your message - your commits are still there with their original messages.  It's just that the merge commit is there to represent the state of your tree when changes from both of your `master` branches are merged.  (Look at the ASCII-art graph with the `M` commit in my answer...)

Answer (score 1):

are you in the same repo or on different repos? If you are you need to rebase your changes and push again

```
git pull --rebase github master
git push github master
```

Comment: fyi, --rebase puts your commit on top of your friends commit so you can push without merging or better you make your history linear again.

Comment: what did you mean 'differente repos'? we all use the same github repo. is this what you mean?

Comment: --rebase doesn't remove anything if you edited and commited file B and your friend file A.